Copy rigid body keyframes on multiple objects
I am animating a group of objects. They are all rigid bodies. In the rigid body physics of one object I have created two keyframes to uncheck and check the dynamic box. I need to copy these two keyframes to the rigid body physics of all the other object. I have tried with copy to selected but it only copies the value (on or off) from the current frame but not the keyframes. Is there a way to do that?

Select all the objects, make the one with keyframes active, then Ctrl L > Link Animation Data?

thanks it works

Select all the objects, make the one with keyframes active, then CtrlL > Link Animation Data.

thanks it works
